# Delete node in the linked list

Tags: c, for-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list, free

Given the head of a linked list and an integer `val`, remove all the nodes of the linked list that have `Node.val == val`, and return the new head.

This is my attempt

```
struct ListNode *removeElements(struct ListNode *head, int val) {
    struct ListNode *tmp, *prev;

    if (head == NULL)
        return head;

    for (tmp = head, prev = NULL; tmp != NULL; prev = tmp, tmp = tmp->next)
        if (tmp->val == val) {
            prev->next = tmp->next;
            free(tmp);
        }

    return head;
}
```

but I got segmentation fault. Problem seems easy, but I don't get where is my mistake.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: You're calling `free(tmp)` then have a *Use-After-Free* bug with `tmp = tmp->next`.

Comment: It'll also be rather bad to do `prev->next = ...` if the first node is one of those you want to remove since `prev` will then be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first node have the value `val`, the statement `prev->next = tmp->next;` will cause a segmentation fault because `prev` is a null pointer.  With your approach, you must make a special case of the start of list:

```
struct ListNode *removeElements(struct ListNode *head, int val) {
    while (head != NULL && head->val == val) {
        struct ListNode *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    if (head != NULL) {
        for (struct ListNode *prev = head, *cur = head->next; cur != NULL;) {
            if (cur->val == val) {
                struct ListNode *tmp = cur;
                prev->next = cur = cur->next;
                free(tmp);
            } else {
                prev = cur;
                cur = cur->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Here is a simpler solution using a double pointer:

```
struct ListNode *removeElements(struct ListNode *head, int val) {
    struct ListNode **pp = &head;
    struct ListNode *tmp;
    while ((tmp = *pp) != NULL) {
        if (tmp->val == val) {
            *pp = tmp->next;
            free(tmp);
        } else {
            pp = &tmp->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This for loop

```
for (tmp = head, prev = NULL; tmp != NULL; prev = tmp, tmp = tmp->next)
    if (tmp->val == val) {
        prev->next = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
```

has three problems.

The main problem is that the loop does not change the pointer (variable)  `head` itself.

So if the data member `val` of the head node is equal to the value of the variable `val` then the value of the pointer `head` will not be changed.

The second problem is that initially the pointer `prev` is equal to `NULL`. So if the node pointed by the pointer `head` will be deleted then there is used a null ponter to access memory in this statement

```
prev->next = tmp->next;
```

that results in undefined behavior.

And at last the third problem is that there can be used already deleted node

```
free(tmp);
```

in the expression of the for loop

```
tmp = tmp->next
```

Also in this case the pointer `prev` is set to the pointer `tmp` that points to the deleted node

```
prev = tmp
```

There can be implemented two approaches.

The first one is at first to check the node pointed by the pointer `head`.

Here you are.

```
struct ListNode * removeElements( struct ListNode *head, int val ) 
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        while ( head->val == val )
        {
            struct ListNode *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            free( tmp );
        }

        if ( head != NULL )
        {
            for ( ListNode *current = head; current->next != NULL; )
            {
                if ( current->next->val == val )
                {
                    ListNode *tmp = current->next;
                    current->next = current->next->next;
                    free( tmp );
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

The second approach is to reference pointers in the list through a pointer to them.

```
struct ListNode * removeElements( struct ListNode *head, int val ) 
{
    for ( struct ListNode **current = &head; *current != NULL; )
    {
        if ( ( *current )->val == val )
        {
            struct ListNode *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Pay attention to that you should always declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.